# Converting generic list to generic array

Tags: java, arrays, generics, linked-list

How can I convert my list, `items` into a `CountedItem[]`?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class CountedSet<E>
{
    LinkedList<CountedItem<E>> items = new LinkedList<CountedItem<E>>();
    private final Comparator<CountedItem<E>> comparator = new Comparator<CountedItem<E>>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(final CountedItem<E> o1, final CountedItem<E> o2)
        {
            return Integer.valueOf(o1.getCount()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2.getCount()));
        }
    };

    public CountedSet()
    {
    }

    public CountedItem<E> add(E item)
    {
        CountedItem<E> currentItem = null;
        for (CountedItem<E> listItem : items)
            if (listItem.getItem().equals(item))
            {
                currentItem = listItem;
                break;
            }

        if (currentItem != null)
            currentItem.increment();
        else
        {
            currentItem = new CountedItem<E>(item);
            items.add(currentItem);
        }

        return currentItem;
    }

    public CountedItem<E>[] getSortedArray()
    {
        Collections.sort(items, this.comparator);

        CountedItem<E>[] array = items.toArraySomeHow();
        return array;
    }
}
```

I do not have many details to give you, besides that I want to do this in `public CountedItem<E>[] getSortedArray()` (last method). Also, doing this causes an error:

```
CountedItem<E>[] array = items.toArray(new CountedItem<E>[items.size()]);
     // ERROR - Cannot create a generic array of CountedItem<E>. ^
```

Comment: java does not support generic arrays

Comment: And there is no way around this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617863/java-convert-generic-linkedlist-to-generic-array

Comment: you can use `items.toArray(new CountedItem[items.size()]);` with warning

Comment: @hoaz +1. This works, and is the easiest solution I've seen... Is this proper though?

Comment: or, to avoid raw types, you can do `items.toArray((CountedItem<E>[])new CountedItem<?>[items.size()]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `items.toArray(new CountedItem[items.size()]);` with warning. But your code is not clean and type safe after this modification.

Also you can add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to get rid of warning.

It is up to you whether you can live with it :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe you can do generic arrays, but you can do a generic ArrayList.  Depending on why you want an array (speed over a linked list?) that might be helpful.  An ArrayList is internally implemented as an `Object[]`.  Something like this perhaps?

```
public CountedItem<E>[] getSortedArray()
{
    Collections.sort(items, this.comparator);

    return new ArrayList<E>(items);
}
```